How to space elements when they are in a ForEach thats in a List?
I have a List with a Section:
VStack {
     List {
          Section(header: Text("Workout Details")) {}
          }
     }

Inside that Section I have a ForEach that will put every set into its own VStack:
        Section(header: Text("Exercises")) {
            if let exercises =  workout.exercises?.sorted(by: { $0.date < $1.date }) {
                ForEach(exercises){ exercise in
                        if let exercisesets = exercise.sets {
                            ForEach(exercisesets) { set in
                                //i want 20 pixels of space between each VStack
                                VStack {
                                    Text("\(exercise.exerciseName.name)")
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("\(set.weight)")
                                        Text("\(set.reps)")
                                    }
                                }
                            
                         
                              
                            
                                
                            }
                        }

                }
                .onDelete(perform: delete)
            } 
            else {
                Text("No Exericses Yet")
            }
           
            //.onDelete(perform: delete)
        }

How would I add space between each of those VStacks so they are separated from each other:

I have attempted to use padding on the bottom:
        Section(header: Text("Exercises")) {
                ForEach(filteredExercises){ exercise in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            
                            Text("\(exercise.exerciseName.name)")
                            if let exercisesets = exercise.sets {
                                ForEach(exercisesets) { set in
                                    //[![enter image description here][2]][2]i want 20 pixels of space vettewn each VStack
                                        HStack {
                                            Text("\(set.weight)")
                                            Text("\(set.reps)")
                                        }
                                    
                                }
                                Divider()
                                Button{
                                    if let exercisesets = exercise.sets {
                                        if(exercisesets.count <= 7) {
                                            let newSet = MySet(id: UUID(), weight: 0, reps: 0,isCompleted: false, exercise: exercise)
                                            //ChatGpt I cannot see this being added until i Refresh the app
                                            modelContext.insert(newSet)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }label: {
                                    Text("Add set")
                                        .underline()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    .padding(.bottom, 50)

but that doesn't separate it the way it should the yellow in the image represents what I want to happen and the red what is currently happening:


Use the padding modifier or a Section for each row or add spacing to the VStack

You could try using ForEach(exercisesets) { set in   VStack (spacing: 20 ) {  VStack{  Text(...) } }
to put 20 pixels of space between each VStack of the ForEach.

Can you draw (or otherwise show) the desired result? Do you want to add an empty list row in between? Or do you want the two list rows to not stick together?

You could try applying .listRowSpacing to the List. But this will take effect for all rows of all sections. So then you could try moving the rows of this section to their own List.

The answer List wont allow this to happen but a fix is to put every element in the ForEach in its own unlabeled section and this will make the desired outcome:
ForEach(filteredExercises){ exercise in
                            Section() {
                                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                    Text("\(exercise.exerciseName.name)")
                                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                    Divider()
                                    SetsView(exercise: exercise)
                                    //ChatGpt why is this button activating when i click on other parts of the VStack
                                    Divider()
                                    Button{
                                        if let exercisesets = exercise.sets {
                                            if(exercisesets.count <= 7) {
                                                let newSet = MySet(id: UUID(), weight: 0, reps: 0,isCompleted: false,date: Date.now , exercise: exercise)
                                                //ChatGpt I cannot see this being added until i Refresh the app
                                                modelContext.insert(newSet)
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }label: {
                                        Text("Add set")
                                            .underline()
                                            .foregroundStyle(.blue)
                                            
                                    }
                                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                                    
                                }
                            }
                            
                        }

